# Correct Noise for NOMA system

Tags: noise, signal-power, bpsk, noma

I am trying to simulate a NOMA system with SIC, but I'm so confusing with the noise expression: $n_m \sim CN(0, \sigma^2_m)$, is zero mean complex additive Gaussian noise with variance at *m*<sup>th</sup> user

where *m* is a specific user and M is total users, i.e users are 1, 2.., *m*,*m*+1,...M

And we have SNR(power units):
$$\gamma = \frac{P}{\sigma^2_m}$$

P is power at the base station. I assume Power at the BS is 1, but How should I create the variance? In NOMA system users' data are superposes in only one carrier, and every user have a power coefficient(if we sum whole power coefficient, the sum is 1 and it has a exponential behavior).
The only way I'm creating my noise is: clear the variance term and converting gamma in dB to obtain SNR range:
$$\sigma^2_m = \frac{P}{SNR}$$

But How create noise for **each** user, if I assume P is equal to 1, for the first users it's "fine" but for latest is terrible because their power is very small, if I assume P is the same coefficient that the user, Successfully Interference Cancelation works fine because first users don't have a considerable noise and error is minimal. I have to create a **specific noise** for **specific user**, What I doing wrong? What power do I use? Is my expressions wrong?

Note:

1. I'm working not with complex noise, just real noise.
2. I've read papers related with SIC and NOMA and they assume the same equations, so I think I'm coding wrong.
3. In matlab I'm doing: `Noise = wgn(Ns,1,10*log10(P/SNR(dB)));`

Comment: I have made some edits, primarily to convert your images of equations to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  (edits may be pending) Please check that I have done so correctly.

Comment: thank you. It looks better

Comment: What do you try to model with the Gaussian random variable $\mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma^2_m)$? Specifically, is it only thermal noise or thermal noise AND signal for all other users that are not the $m$-th user?

Comment: With that Gaussian random variable I try to model just noise. I have already characterized the other terms and have simulated them, I only have problem when simulating my noise, which I suppose must be special for each user.

Comment: The thermal noise is the phenomenon at the receiver and does not depend on the user. Differently put, all users should observe the same noise variance.